# C# while loop it repeats 1bottles and 1 bottle I would like to know how to remove the 1bottles line

Tags: c#

Hi guys I need help solving a c# problem. This is the code being run as you can see it repeats 1bottles and 1 bottle on the picture I would like to know how to remove the "1 bottles on the wall take one down" and keep "1 bottle on the wall"  please help

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string strBottles = "bottles";
        int bottles = 100;           

        while (bottles <= 100)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bottles + strBottles + " on the wall" + " take one down");              
                           
            if(bottles == 1)
            {
                strBottles = "bottle";
                Console.WriteLine(bottles + strBottles + " on the wall");
                break;
            }

            bottles--;
        }
    }    
}
```

[image: and this image is the code being run]

Comment: School homework? This is not what SOF is for.

Comment: its not school homework I promise I'm just a self taught developer trying to learn how to code at my own pace

Answer (score 1):

Think about what the code is doing when `bottles == 1`.

First it hits this line

```
Console.WriteLine(bottles + strBottles + " on the wall" + " take one down");
```

then it enters the `if` statement:

```
if(bottles == 1)
{
    strBottles = "bottle";
    Console.WriteLine(bottles + strBottles + " on the wall");
    break;
}
```

If you want only the "1bottle on the wall", then the `if` statement needs to come first:

```
while (bottles > 0)
{
    if(bottles == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{bottles} bottle on the wall");
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine($"{bottles} bottles on the wall take one down");                             
    
    bottles--;
}
```

Other improvements:

- `while (bottles <= 100)` - `bottles` starts at 100 and decreases so this statement will always be true. If you changed the initial number of bottles to `int bottles = 101` the code wouldn't execute the `while` loop in your version. You never want it to go below `1` so the condition should be `while (bottles > 0)`
- You don't really need the string `strBottles`, it's redundant and can be removed
- If you're using C# 6.0 or above take a look at [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). It provides a more readable way to format strings with expressions: `$"{bottles} bottles on the wall"`

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the value before the first message printing, add an `if` check like so,

```
if(bottles>1)
  Console.WriteLine(bottles + strBottles + " on the wall" + " take one down");
```

Answer (score 1):

Choosing a possible infinite do/while with a break condition that can or cannot be fullfilled is a bad idea
I will try this aproach:

```
        string strBottle = "bottle";
        int iBottles = 100;
        for (int bottles = iBottles; bottles >=1; bottles--)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(bottles + strBottle + (bottles>1?"s":"") +" on the wall" + (bottles > 1 ? " take one down":""));
        }
```